# Which is the better css framework for a magento 2 custom theme?

Tags: magento2, theme

If you have to create a custom theme which is the better css framework for magento 2 and why? Or it is better not to use any of them?

- Bootstrap
- Foundation
- None
- Another one

please write the motivations

Answer (score 0):

If youre a beginner (assuming you are, hence the question), stick to Bootstrap, it is the most popular and has the biggest community.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm not a beginner, I have 10 years of experience in ecommerce development but i want to have a discussion about ;) i'm using bootstrap but i'm not sure is the best solution to use an third parts framework

Comment: I see. I don't know what is there to argue about, there are many comparisons online and I see no reason why Magento should be an exception. But, for example, the most popular Magento theme "Ultimo" (https://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798) is built on Bootstrap.